# .exe из .py = большой вес и долгий запуск

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe, pyinstaller

Создаю оконное приложение на PyQT. Берутся данные из одного экселя, производится довольно простой расчет с использованием только нампая, и его результат сохраняется в другой эксель с помощью ДатаФрейма. Файлы ввода и вывода выбираются с помощью диалогового окна.

Собираю .exe через: `pyinstaller -F -w` (отключаю вручную все не нужные модули через `--exclude-module`). Но в итоге этот *.exe* весит **300 мб** и запускается по 50 секунд.  Ну это же не серьезно.

*.py* весит 9 кб, а экзешник 300 мб. Да если его папкой собирать, там .dll весят сами по себе около 300 мб все вместе взятые, всякие mkl_core и прочие. Хотелось бы создать невесомый и быстрый экзешник, а на выходе какая-то жесть.

Может кто-то подсобит советом? Это вообще возможно? И как тогда все это урезать? `UPX` пробовал - не помогает, срезает максимум до 250 мб и "ломает" .dll.

Comment: скрипт то хоть и весит мало, но вы не забывайте, что к нему в комплекте идет еще и среда, и интерпретатор, так что малого веса не ожидайте.. да и насчет скорости - python не самый скоростной.

Comment: @finally но 50с и 300мб всё равно не очень нормальные показатели, даже для pyqt

Comment: Потому что pyinstaller, как и другие упаковщики, создают самораспаковываемый архив, содержащий интерпретатор Python, все необходимые библиотеки и сам скрипт, а не полноценный исполняемый файл программы. Хотите компактных исполняемых файлов - используйте компилируемый язык программирования.